# Which slf4j .jar dependency do I need?

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

I'm getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

I need to include slf4j as a dependency but I'm not sure which jar file to download from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/.

I tried `org/slf4j/slf4j-ap`i which doesn't work. How do I determine which one is correct?

Comment: https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html have you tried looking at the documentation? you need the api and an implementation. SLF4j is a facade over existing frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

`slf4j` is a library that is used as an abstraction of each logging implementation framework such as `log4j`, `logback` or `Jakarta Commons Logging`. If your intent is to use it, you have to also define the concrete framework you want to use under the wood, for example for `log4j`, your `pom` dependencies will look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Depending on the framework you want to use, the dependencies will be a bit different.

This excellent [link](https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-with-log4j2-logback) will give your more details.

Comment: Log4J 1.x is not actively developed and suffers from severe CVE's. Use Logback (which naturally implements slf4J) or Log4J 2.x instead.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet thanks, I know. It is just for an illustration of how dependencies are declared.

Answer (score 1):

SLF4J is a logging API. Combine it with Logback (written by the same people as SLF4J) which implements that logging API:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Find the latest stable versions on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic). Currently logback 1.2.11 and slf4J 1.7.32. Note the the vulnerabilities mentioned on logback 1.2.11 are because of an optional dependency on log4J 1.x (which you don't get automatically, so it's safe to use logback 1.2.11 at the time of writing).